# glTranslatef moves diagonally instead of on major axes

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to move my object on x axis on key press. But it looks like it is moving diagonally(up left and down right) Here is my code : 
Key press code :

```
switch(key)
{
case 'a':
x++;
break;

case 'b':
x--;
break;
}
```

on OpenGL part :

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
glLoadIdentity();   
gluPerspective(30, 1 , 1 , 1000);   

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();


gluLookAt(100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0,  0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(x;0,0);
```

Why is glTranslatef is working that strangely, how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Post *all* the relevant parts of your code. See http://sscce.org/ . `glTranslatef(x;0,0);` is not even c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most probably rotating before you translate. This will rotate the entire coordinate space and your "translation along the x axis" will actually be something completely different.

In future, make sure you translate, scale, then rotate. This way each transformation will do what you intend without being manipulated by a prior transformation. I suggest you look into matrices, coordinate  spaces, and OpenGL a bit more.

Also, glTranslatef and other matrix stack functions are deprecated. Look into modern OpenGL.

EDIT:

gluLookAt does a rotation to face the look at point. So, there is a rotation involved. Switch them around if you don't want this. Also, that isn't your full code, it's missing glMatrixMode calls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is no rotate in the code. And by the way translation along y axis works perfectly correct. But it doesn't work on x and z axis.

Comment: Okay. Can you explain in more detail what's happening? Can you edit your posts with all your transformations?

Comment: I have edited the question. There is really one transformation. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my question again. Can you tell me how to get rid of gluLookAt's effect? Thank you very much.